# Workmanager is not working when the constraint is setup (Android)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-workmanager

I created a `OneTimeWorkRequest` with constraint `setRequiredCharging` to true...

When I plug the charger it shows the notification as expected...

But when I start the work in discharging mode it shows enqueued as expected...

But the real problem is when I plugged my phone it must show the notification indicates that the work is done... But it is not happening.. Why???

Thanks in advance

If you don't understand my question ask me once

Comment: It would be useful to understand if the application reports any issue in the logcat. You can take a look at the documentation: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/debugging

Also the advanced codelab shows how to enable logging with a custom initialization: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-adv-workmanager/index.html?index=..%2F..index#3

Comment: No bro .. I checked the log... Nothing happening... It is not even entering to doWork method

Comment: without some code it is difficult to know what it is going on, in particular how you enqueue your Worker.
You can try with the WorkManager codelab that uses that same constraints on the third worker:  https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-workmanager/index.html?index=..%2F..index#10